# C# Can namespaces only access methods which are declared with the static keyword?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. The question i had was regarding namespaces. This is what i have.

namespace A
{

```
namespace B {

   public class Family {

        public static void Print() {   

            Console.WriteLine("HIIIIIIIII");
        
        }

    }

}
```

}

Now I can access the method "Print" in the main using
---------------A.B.Family.Print();-------------------

But I cannot access the Print method if i remove the static keyword in the declaration. Is it because you can only access static methods inside a namespace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is about the time you read the documentation, all the information is there for you and the answer to more questions you are likely to ask in the future  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods can be called the way you showed.
Non static methods (also called instance methods) need an object instance so that you call.

So in order to call your methods after you remove `static` keyword from your method you need to create an object instance.

For example:

```
var myFamily = new A.B.Family();
myFamily.Print();
```

For more info refer to [C# Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods#:%7E:text=Invoking%20an%20instance%20method%20requires,not%20operate%20on%20instance%20data.)